# Mysql server is not running in windows 7

Tags: mysql, installation

I'm trying to work with MySQL workbench for a javaEE project. First I've installed  MySQL server 5.6.20 and then MySQL workbench and finally connector j. After opening workbench I've made a connection with default setting, this is Host:127.0.0.1;Port:3306;User:root. When I tested connection this massage showed:

> failed to connect mysql at 127.0.0.1:3306 with user root
> Blockquote
>
> can't connect to mysql server on 127.0.0.1(10061)

Then I opened connection and from schemas tried to star server, but it didn't started. After that I tried to start MySQL from windows services, but there I didn't find any MySQL. Then I tried to install MySQL as windows service using this tutorial  [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/windows-start-service.html) , but whenever I enter below command in console it shows install/remove of the service denied!

> C:> "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld" --install-manual

Can any one help me about this problem?I'm actually not realizing what to do now at all.

Comment: Run command prompt as administrator and try again.

Comment: Please can you  tell me How can I Run command prompt as administrator ?whenever I start cmd it directly starts.

Comment: Its not the best way to do it, but since i dont know what version of windows u are runnig, u can do:
find cmd.exe in C:\Windows\System32\ right click -> Run as Administrator.

Comment: You welcome, i think u should write an answer how did u solve the problem and accept it. ;]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below command should be run as administrator from the cmd.

> C:> "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld" --install-manual

To open cmd as administrator, go start menu and search for cmd.Do not select cmd directly.right click it and open as administrator and then type

> cd C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\

enter and then type

> mysql --install-manual

enter

Answer (score 1):

why didn't you try installing the mysql server via the workbench. I think this should help the situation. Remove the server and try installing it through the workbench...if needs be also remove the workbench and do a fresh install. Please backup any data or file that needs backing up.

Comment: this is more a comment

Comment: What is the process? I mean what to do after installing workbench?

Comment: @udoyen many many thanks. todor's solution worked for me.But in future I will remember your solution. :)